# Creating session based on Google sign in

Tags: authentication, google, authorization, oauth2

Does it make sense to implement your own session management on top of the Google sign in?

Scenario:
I have a web app where I allow users to sign in with Google. I just need this sign in to verify the identity of the user, but the things that the user can do on my app do not really depend on whether they are signed in to Google or not. Once I get the success response from Google Oauth, I am planning to consider that as a login for my app and create an independent session for my application.

Is this a suggested approach? Are there any security or application concerns?

Comment: What about people that don't have a Google account?

Comment: in this case, I mean any oauth provider (or multiple oauth providers). The question is mainly about whether it is a good practice to create your own session on top of the oauth setup

Comment: I some issue on your approach. From one side you do not care in your application if the user is logged in. But from the other side you want to have user logged-in. I suppose you are not mentioning about some obvious needs. Don't you possibly want to know something about the user in your app?

Comment: Use OpenID instead of pure OAuth, as OAuth isn't meant to definitively identify a user to your application.

Comment: @BartoszRosa we might want to get some user details from google for the first time they are logged in, but not all the time

Comment: Ok. But what you mean "on top of oauth setup"? Do you mean that you want strictly relate from Google/other provider session?

Comment: oauth in this case is just used for authentication / verifying user identity. Once we know that the user is verified, our application can create an independent session for this user using its own cookie or jwt